# Detect Swipe speed mobile jquery

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile

I am using phonegap to make app for andriod and iphone . I want to detect the speed of swipe for better user experience . Is there any way that i can achieve this through mobile jquery or any other library .

Thanks

Comment: well you would use relative averaging with coordinates. something ud have to build. for example how much time did it take too A to B. what "group" does this fall into that youve predefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently updated my [jQuery Mobile Events](https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Mobile-Events) to include a new event `swipeend`.

The `swipeend` event is triggered when a swipe has been successfully executed, and the library provides a useful set of data for use in a callback function. If you read through the docs, it'll be clear how you could calculate the speed (assuming you use the `S = D / T` algorithm:

For example, you could use my library as follows:

```
$('#myElement').swipeend(function(e, touch) { 
    var speed = touch.xAmount / touch.duration; // Gives speed in pixels/millisecond
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GHt7T/) for you.

Comment: Thanks BenM i will be using ur libraray :)

Comment: not working for direction change. you are suggesting only a mere average between start and end point of touch, not the expected human touch... example: if you start from the very left, move your finger to the very right, wait a second, then swipe to the left very quickly... speed ~= 0.